# Share Type Alias among different files in one namespace

Tags: c#

I have defined a type alias, and I can use it in my class that I've declared in this file.

```cs
using TemplateStructure = System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<DataManagement.TemplateImageLocation>>;

namespace Gui.ViewModels
{
    public class AddRemoveCellsViewModel : TemplateWorkflowStepViewModel
    {
        public TemplateViewModel TemplateVM
        {
            get;
        }

        public AddRemoveCellsViewModel(TemplateStructure locations) : base(locations)
        {
            base.DisplayName = "Add and Remove Rows/Columns";
            TemplateVM = new TemplateViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

But another class in another file, in the same namespace, it doesn't work.

```cs
namespace Gui.ViewModels
{
    public class ActivateDeactivateCellsViewModel : TemplateWorkflowStepViewModel
    {
        // FAILS
        public ActivateDeactivateCellsViewModel(TemplateStructure locations) : base(locations)
        {
            base.DisplayName = "Click to deactivate image locations";
        }
    }
}
```

And, of course, usings must be placed outside of a namespace declaration.

Is it possible to use this Type Alias in multiple files?

Comment: As far as I know only by adding it again in the top of every file. It's actually not about sharing aliases, but about sharing `using`s/Imports at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write

```
using TemplateStructure = System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.List<DataManagement.TemplateImageLocation>>;
```

In every file where you want to use this alias, because

> A *using_alias_directive* introduces an identifier that serves as an alias for a namespace or type within *the immediately enclosing compilation unit or namespace body*.
>
> (from [C# Language Specification - Using alias directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/namespaces#using-alias-directives))

Using-aliases do not work across *compilation-units*, which are:

> A C# program consists of one or more compilation units, each contained in a separate source file.
>
> (from [C# Language Specification - Compilation units](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/namespaces#compilation-units))